Как исправить эту ошибку? ModuleNotFoundError
текст ошибки:
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'app'
  File "C:\Users\inast\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\чат бот проект\app\handlers.py", line 5, in <module>
    import app.keybords as kb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

струтура проекта:
enter image description here
код handlers:
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command

import app.keybords as kb

router = Router()


> @router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
await message.answer("hello", reply_markup=kb.main) 
await message.reply("how are you?") 


> @router.message(Command("help"))
async def cmd_help(message: Message):
await message.answer("you put on helpful tab")


> @router.message(F.text == "every nice")
async def nice(message: Message):
await message.answer("i`m happy")

код main:
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

from app.handlers import router



async def main():
bot = Bot(token='token')
dp = Dispatcher()
dp.include_router(router)
await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__": 
try:
asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
print("bot`s stop")

код keybords:
from aiogram.types import KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup

main = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[[KeyboardButton(text='basket')],
                                     [KeyboardButton(text='contacts')],
                                     [KeyboardButton(text='for our'),
                                     KeyboardButton(text='catalog')]])


я не понимаю что ему надо....

Как запускаете код? Какую строку для запуска используете?

В папке app создайте файл __init.py__.

при запуске f5 нажимаю только

окей попробуем.

не работает так тоже((

@mvskl скорее всего не может определить каталог для поиска модулей. Пробуй в .vscode/settings.json добавить такую строку "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env", а в корень проекта положи файл .env с такой строкой PYTHONPATH=.

@AlexanderLonberg, а вдруг у человека не vscode?

@mvski, пробовали в handlers использовать импорт keybords или .keybords вместо app.keybords?

@PaveTranquil Я сомневаюсь что у других редакторов будут иконки над панелью навигатора в точности повторять VSCode, обрати внимание на его скрин.

@AlexanderLonberg, а ой, да, действительно, не обратил внимание на интерфейс)
